# How can I make a command to delete all channels?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a discord bot in discord.jsV12 that auto sets up a server. For this to happen i need the bot to delete all channels. I have tried `msg.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())`
But nothing happens and I get 0 errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might want to check these pages first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
without further details it's hard to help you

Comment: Your attempt is the way to go, we will need more of your code example to see what really went wrong.

Comment: What `discord.js` version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What you attempted is actually the solution.

You can use it on the message object, which means it's an action after you make a message, like so:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '.deleteChannels') {
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete());
  }
});
```

> triggered by making a discord message **containing** ".deleteChannels"

- Make sure your bot has permissions to delete channels as well.
- Be aware that this is a reply to a message. Otherwise, `message` would not be defined.

Answer (score 0):

`discord.js v12+` uses `Managers`, which means you'll have to go through an extra step and pass through the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) property.

```js
msg.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete());
```

---

- [Guide to switch from `v11` to `v12`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)
- [More info about updating](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/updating)